# How to loop strings in Python/Matplotlib?

Tags: python, string, loops, matplotlib

I have a practical question commonly seen in Matplotlib, that many times I will have to write

```
ax.set_xlim([-5, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
ax.set_zlim([0, 5])
```

I am wonder is there a way of looping through them?

I searched that there is one possible way to loop them is to use `eval()`. But I haven't figure out exactly it can be done with it.

Is there a clever way of looping this? Thanks!

Comment: these are three different functions with 3 different inputs (2 unique in this case)...writing a loop would actually almost certainly be more code than this or at minimum contain basically the exact same code in another form... what do you mean by loop?

Comment: Since you'll need to provided upper and lower limits for all three axes in any case, whatever you come up with will still have 6 inputs - you could write something that allows you to set all limits in one go, similar to `ax.set_lims([-5, 5], [-5, 5], [0, 5])` but I don't think that all that much more clear. And how often do you have to set limits for your axes that you think this is worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

If this is all you're doing, it's probably easiest to type it out every time.
You can save a tiny bit of typing, for some loss of clarity, by setting the x and y limits with a single call; but the z limits remain separate:

```
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.set_zlim([zmin, zmax])
```

If you're doing this very often, you could create a utilities module, and start collecting functions for code snippets you use a lot.

E.g. you might find it useful to have a single function to create the 3D projection, and set the limits and labels:

```
def setup3d(fig, lims=None, labels=None):
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    if lims:
        ax.set_xlim(*lims[0:2])
        ax.set_ylim(*lims[2:6])
        ax.set_zlim(*lims[4:6])
    if labels:
        ax.set_xlabel(labels[0])
        ax.set_ylabel(labels[1])
        ax.set_zlabel(labels[2])
    return ax

fig = plt.figure()
ax = setup3d(fig, [-2, 2, 1, 5, -5, 5], ['my X', 'YYY' ,'Z'])
```